# Django: sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table in python shell

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I'm following a django blog tutorial. When I used `python manage.py shell` and tried following commands in shell

```
from mainsite.models import Category, Tag
c = Category(name='category test')
c.save()
```

this error occured:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: mainsite_category
```

This is my model.py in `mainsite` folder, which I think is correct:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

I have tried `manage.py makemigrations`, `manage.py migrate` and can successfully use `manage.py runserver` to see the website. So what is wrong here?

Edit: this is my INSTALLED APP in `settings.py`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'mainsite',
]
```

And my project structure

```
|____djangoBlog
| |______init__.py
| |____settings.py
| |____urls.py
| |____wsgi.py
|____mainsite
| |______init__.py
| |____admin.py
| |____apps.py
| |____models.py
| |____tests.py
| |____urls.py
| |____views.py
|____manage.py
|____README.md
|____requirements.txt
|____templates
| |____blog
| | |____index.html
```

Edit: When I run `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`, the output is as follows:

```
No changes detected

Operations to perform:
    Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
    No migrations to apply.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPD:**

Since your project structure is lack of `migrations` folder in `mainsite` app, it means that you haven't created migrations for that app. Run `python manage.py makemigrations mainsite` and then `python manage.py migrate`.

From [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-makemigrations):

> To add migrations to an app that doesn’t have a **`migrations`** directory, run **`makemigrations`** with the app’s **`app_label`**.

And yes, you can create model with simple instance creation. From docs [Creating objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/instances/#creating-objects).

**Original answer:**

You need to be sure that you've included your `'mainsite'` app in `INSTALLED_APPS` in *settings.py* and then run migrations. After that you should be able to do the following:

```
c = Category.objects.create(name='category test')
c.save()
```

Comment: This doesn't work, the same error still occurs and it occurs earlier(Just after I enter `c = Category.objects...`.

Comment: @Owen can you provide your project structure and part of settings.py with INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: I edited the question. I wrote this program in another computer and use git to pull it to current computer.

Comment: @Owen you don't have `migrations` folder in your `mainsite` app, what it means is that you haven't created and run migrations of the app

Comment: I tried `makemigrations` and `migrate` but nothing happened(as edited). So what should I do to solve it?

Comment: It works, thanks! But why is it so? Should I always use this command instead of `python manage.py makemigrations`?

Comment: And the origin `c = Category(name='category test')` also works. So maybe it's better to move the solution in comment to answer.

Comment: @Owen thanks, i've edited answer with useful links and solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

@Owen, 
According to vishes_shell's answer, you'll have to do :

```
python manage.py makemigrations mainsite
```

the first time in order to generate a folder migrations that will contain your migrations, then you can just do

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

In the futur if you add a new app, don't forget to make again the first command (changing the "mainsite" by the name of your app) before using the second one.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like in your `models.py` you need an indentation at `name`:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Comment: I believe missing indentation is a consequence of copy-paste. Also you missed your indentation for __str__ method.

Comment: Yes, me too. But I remember to have this kind of errors without any Django warning.